# YouTrack notifications aren`t working

Tags: youtrack

We have stand-alone YT installation, one project and two users.
First user receives all notifications to his email, but I recieve nothing.
I receive email in case when I click on `Send test message` in my profile settings page. 
On filters and notifications tab I have all checkboxes checked.

*Any ideas how to fix this?*

Comment: I've been having similar issues on the hosted version. One user receives no notifications, but has everything checked. Another receives notifications for the wrong person. JetBrains has ignored our support requests.

Comment: We found some workaround, but not solution: you can enable Jabber notifications, this feature works fine.

Comment: Now we have three users. And it works as follows: first user has all messages. Second (I'm) has messages for third. And third don't receive any messages.

Comment: It turned out someone had messed with the filter definitions so "Tickets assigned to me" was something entirely different. Check your tags/filters.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow this link and enable all of the notification.

[enable all of the notification](https://devxhub.myjetbrains.com/youtrack/users/me?tab=notifications)

Comment: This link leads to your company YouTrack page

Answer (score -1):

check on http://{your-youtrack-url}/user#tab=Filters%20and%20Notifications for the configured notifications. For a new user we had the case, that NO notification wer setup.

Comment: On filters and notifications tab I have all checkboxes checked. I wrote it before.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are discussing YouTrack (often abbreviated as YT), a popular issue and project tracking tool developed by JetBrains. Based on the information you provided, here are some steps you can take to troubleshoot and potentially resolve the issue of not receiving email notifications:

**1. Check Spam/Junk Folder:** Ensure that YouTrack notifications are not ending up in your spam or junk email folder. If they are, mark them as "Not Spam" or "Not Junk" and consider adding the YouTrack email address to your contacts or whitelist.

**2. Verify Profile Email:** Ensure that the email address in your YouTrack profile is correctly spelled and is the email where you wish to receive notifications.

**3. Notification Rules:**

- Go to your profile settings.
- Navigate to "Notifications" tab.
- Ensure that the projects and issues you wish to be notified about are properly selected.
- Make sure that the notification channels (like Email) are correctly configured.

**4. Subscription Settings:** In YouTrack, you can also set up subscriptions to specific issues, queries, or tags. Ensure you are subscribed to relevant issues or queries. This is especially important if you're expecting notifications for new issues or specific tags.

**5. Notification Scheme:**

- If your YouTrack instance is using a custom notification scheme, it's possible that some events don't trigger notifications.
- An admin should verify the notification scheme applied to your project to ensure it is configured correctly.

**6. SMTP Server Configuration:** Since you mentioned you do receive a test email, it's likely the SMTP server is correctly configured. However, inconsistencies or intermittent issues might arise from SMTP server settings. Ask the person managing the YouTrack instance to ensure the SMTP settings are correct and test the connection.

**7. YouTrack Logs:** Check the server logs for any errors or warnings related to sending email. This might reveal issues like failed email delivery or issues connecting to the SMTP server.

**8. Verify User Role and Permissions:** Ensure that your user role has permissions to receive notifications for the events you're interested in. Sometimes, roles may have limited permissions which might prevent certain notifications.

**9. Verify Filters:** On the "Filters and Notifications" tab, there's an option to mute specific notifications. Ensure you haven't unintentionally muted certain notifications.

**10. Check Issue Visibility:** If you're expecting notifications from specific issues, ensure that you have visibility permissions for those issues. Sometimes, issues might be restricted to certain user groups or roles.

**11. Test with Another Email:** As a troubleshooting step, try changing your profile email to another email address and see if you receive notifications there. This might help in identifying if the issue is with your email service provider or the YouTrack setup.

**12. Version & Updates:** Ensure that your YouTrack installation is running the latest version. Sometimes, bugs related to notifications can be fixed in newer versions.

If you've checked all the above points and are still facing the issue, you might want to contact JetBrains support or consult the YouTrack community forums for more specific assistance.